# Ajax - access beforesend xhr

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to do a redirect from ajax requests. When a session expires my backend redirects to the login page instead of sending data. But as it has been discussed on StackOverflow before, ajax does not handle redirects.

Instead of updating all my ajax requests one by one to handle the status `401`, I am overriding them with `ajaxSetup`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:(xhr) => {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(xhr.status);
        if (xhr.status === 401) {
            window.location.replace(_baseUrl);
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting the required status for the redirects but the problem is I am not being able to access the `status` variable from the `XMLHttpRequest` request.

`console.log(xhr);`:

> ...
> status: 401
> statusCode: ƒ (e)
> statusText: "Unauthorized"
> then: ƒ (t,i,o)
> [[Prototype]]: Object

`console.log(xhr.status);`:

> undefined

Comment: I mean, you can't access the response before it is sent.. This action would need to occur on complete or error.

Comment: @KevinB I replaced `beforeSend` with `complete` but the 2 `console.logs` are not outputting anything. Is there any way I can accomplish what I want with `ajaxSetup` or do I have to update all my ajax requests individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.ajaxComplete()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) event instead of `$.ajaxSetup()`. Try this

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(xhr.status);
    if (xhr.status === 401) {
        window.location.replace(_baseUrl);
    }
});
```